# Firebase Total Number of Registered user in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an app that does authentication of user through  google account. The authentication is working perfectly fine. And I need to find total user.

How to find the count of total number of users from Authentication Section?
Is there a way to retrieve count of number of users in Firebase Android.

Answer (score 4):

You can use firebase cloud functions to achieve this.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events

```
exports.onUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
return admin.database().ref('/totalUsers').once('value').then(snapshot => {
  var count = snapshot.val();
  count = count + 1;
  return admin.database().ref('/totalUsers').set(count);
});
});

exports.onUserDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
return admin.database().ref('/totalUsers').once('value').then(snapshot => {
  var count = snapshot.val();
  count = count - 1;
  return admin.database().ref('/totalUsers').set(count);
});
});
```

You have to initialize count as 0 in your database node

```
xxxxx-xxxx.firebaseio.com/totalUsers
```

Answer (score 1):

From the console, the number of users currently registered should be visible on the lower-right side of the Authentication Page:

[image]

There is currently no API to retrieve the number of users that was registered through Firebase Authentication.

As a workaround, you could make use of [Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), storing the users there after registration, then retrieving a the count from there. Note that it's always good to make sure that users are only able to read data that they need.